# Why does this image take some margin when no margin has been applied?

Tags: html, css

I take two image in anchor tag .when I don't give margin it show in same **plan/level** which is fine .

```
#one{
    margin:0px;
     border:1px solid red
}
```

but when I give margin to first image  it come down down .It fine .but why second image come down .I did not give any margin to second image ? It should display same level as first .

```
#one{
    margin:100px;
     border:1px solid red
}
```

in other words I didn't give any margin to second image but but it display below some margin to second ? why it is not display along with first image as it display when margin is **zeopPX**

http://jsfiddle.net/8u640djs/2/

Comment: I'm not sure what your'e asking, are you aware that "margin:100px" applies margin to *all* sides of the image?

Comment: Are you talking about the space between the first and the second image, or the space between the left window edge and the second image? The former is due to the `margin: 100px` in the first image, and the latter is due to the default body margin defined in the `user-agent-stylesheet` that browser provides.

Comment: just use this `#one{ margin:100px 100px 0; }`

Comment: @Jon please write more descriptive edit comments in future

Comment: @JonKantner, I didn't "forget" to edit the body of the question. But for the body to be grammatically correct would basically require a full re-write, which I felt would conflict with the intent and personal style of the author, so I just focused on the title, to at least make the question clear and searchable.

Comment: @Michael It was me who forgot to edit a part of the question.

Comment: @JonKantner, The comment in the edit wasn't clear. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you gave the first image a 100px margin *on all sides*. Hence, the right and bottom margins are impacting the second image.

To illustrate this behavior, adjust the margin shorthand to include all values:

```
margin: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
```

Then change one value to 0 and test, and repeat for each value. You'll see what's happening.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8u640djs/3/

Answer (score -1):

This is because `a` elements are  vertically aligned on bottom. Add

`a{
vertical-align: middle; 
display: inline-block;
}`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8u640djs/6/

Answer (score -1):

You have to change alignment of img tag by `vertical-align`

```
#one{
    margin:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```